# How can I find Value for Max from a GROUP BY

Tags: sql-server

I want to group my data by Date and then find "Value" for MAX("SeqNumber"). How can I do this in an aggregate query.

I tried the below, but it gives and error.

> Column 'MyTable.SeqNumber' is invalid in the select list because it is
>   not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
>   Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 22 Column 'MyTable.Value' is invalid
>   in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate
>   function or the GROUP BY clause.

```
Columns:

Date: date
Time: time
Value: float
Code: varchar  <<Added in EDIT
SeqNumber: int
```

> Edited query:

```
SELECT MAX(case [Code] when 'GOLD' then [Value] end) AS BestGold, 
       MAX(case [Code] when 'SILVER' then [Value] end) as BestSilver
       (CASE WHEN [SeqNumber]=MAX([SeqNumber]) THEN [Value] END) AS HIGHEST << Problem
FROM [MyTable]
GROUP BY [Date]
```

Comment: I don't want MAX([Value]), I want [Value] where SeqNumber = "MaxOfGroup"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can achieve this by using using group by and sub query -

```
select t1.* 
from [MyTable] t1 join 
( SELECT 
  MAX([SeqNumber]) as MX_SeqNumber  -- you can add your additional columns here 
  FROM [MyTable]
  GROUP BY [Date] ) as t2
on t1.[SeqNumber] = t2.MX_SeqNumber
```

Comment: Where are you returing [Value] for MAX([SeqNumber])?

Comment: As you can see in the last line of the code  --> "on t1.[SeqNumber] = t2.MX_SeqNumber". This means i am joining SeqNumber with MX_SeqNumber . Ex - for 12th Dec if we have 5 seqNum from 1-5 than the the subquery (t2) will return only 5 and the join at the end will filter out the seqNum from 1-4 and return the row where seqnum = 5 from t1

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT *,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [Date] ORDER BY Sequence DESC) AS RN
    FROM YourTable)
SELECT [Value] AS Highest
FROM CTE
WHERE RN = 1;
```

Comment: I think you have forgotten the GROUP BY here

Comment: @ManInMoon No, I haven't. It's not there, because it's not needed.

Comment: To give each row a row Number, @ManInMoon. [ROW_NUMBER (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql). It orders the row numbering by your Sequence (in descending order) and partition's by `[Date]` (which is the like your `GROUP BY [Date]` in your query). Then, it simply returns only the value of `[Value]` where the column `RN` has a value of `1`.

Comment: I need the GROUP BY structure as I am finding other things like MAX and MINs. I just simplified for this question

Comment: Then you need to provide more detail in your question. The answers you'll get are going to be for your simplified version. If we don't know what your full query is, we can't answer.